# Magdeburg hemispheres with wall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

In the famous Magdeburg hemisphere experiment up to about 30 horses were used pulling on *both sides* of the hemispheres.

Could I achieve the same effect (same force on the hemispheres) if I replaced half the horses with a wall, i.e. attach the hemispheres on one side with a wall and have 15 horses pull on the other side?

Comment: Not clear what point you are trying to make. If the wall is strong enough, why do you think it might not replace the horses? What difference do you think the horses make?

Comment: Possibly your issue is that in [Active and passive pulling - is there a physical difference?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/402002) or [Why I think tension should be twice the force in a tug of war](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41291)

Comment: I think my question is whether Newton's 3rd law (action=reaction) applies, i.e. whether the wall exerts a force on the hemispheres that is equal to that of 15 horses.